# Call a function from an object defined in data() Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an object (requestParams) in data :

```
data () {
  return {
    requestParams:{
      controller : '',
      data : {
        username : "arman",
        password : "1234"
      },
      callBack: function() {
        this.testFunct()
      }
    }
  }
},
```

And in methods:{} I have :

```
methods: {
  clickedButton()
  {
    this.$store.dispatch('postRequest', {self:this})
  },
  testFunct: function()
  {
    alert(123)
  }
},
```

The "clickedButton" function, calls a method from actions.js and then the actions.js calls the callBack function from requestParams like this :

```
self.requestParams.callBack();
```

The requestParams.callBack() trigger successfully but this.testFunct() returns this error :

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.testFunct is not a function
```

How can i call "testFunct" in an object in data() ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct answer to your question depends a little bit on version of ES you are using.
If you are using ES6 (or higher), then you can use [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) like this:

```
data () {
  return {
    requestParams:{
      controller : '',
      data : {
        username : "arman",
        password : "1234"
      },
      callBack: () => { // arrow function does not redeclare `this`
        this.testFunct()
      }
    }
  }
},
```

If you are using ES5, then you should assign `this` to any local variable inside your `data` method:

```
data () {
  var that = this;
  return {
    requestParams:{
      controller : '',
      data : {
        username : "arman",
        password : "1234"
      },
      callBack: function() {
        that.testFunct() // using `that`, not `this`
      }
    }
  }
},
```

And of course you can use second variant with ES6.